# Shell script for a Git Repo

Tags: python, shell

I need to create a shell script (run.sh) file that executes my python code present in Git repository and append it to the repo. Since this is my first time, I am confused about how to create the run.sh file and in what language.

Comment: "I need to create a shell script"...."in what language?"...Uh, a flavor of shell script, probably bash :P

Comment: I suggest you simply run your script directly, i.e. make your script the `run.sh` file. What's the reason for a separate script? Other then that stick with Python, again, I don't find any reason to use other language if you already know Python. BTW: why is that question tagged "bigdata" and "github"?

Comment: @freakish Clever answer. There's a lot going inside my mind and I got confused about creating separate script. I am working with bigdata....tagged it in order to know if it makes a difference in terms of running the code efficiently. Thanks for your help...I am relieved!!

Comment: @NightShadeQueen Excuse my innocence....my mind is preoccupied :) I am in a rush.

Comment: "how to create the run.sh ..." Presumably with an editor. "in what language..." Well, you could pick from quite a few, and many would be suitable, but as mentioned by @freakish, why not just stick to Python?

Comment: I have a Github repo with my source code for a particular task written in python. I am required to include a shell script that compiles & runs my program. My question is...how do I create this shell script. :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the output is in stdout, something like this might work:

```
#! /bin/bash

python main.py >> log
git add log
git commit -m 'update log'
git push -u origin
```

I have to admit though, I'm not sure this is what you are asking for. Please clarify :)

Comment: Hi Kota, thanks for the answer.
I have a Github repo with my source code for a particular task written in python. I am required to include a shell script that compiles & runs my program. My question is...how do I create this shell script. :(

Comment: If it is in Python, there is no need to compile it. You just need to run it. Put `#! /bin/bash` on the first line of run.sh so that the system knows what to run it with, and on the second line, `python main.py` or whatever the command is to run the Python script. Then, call `chmod +x run.sh` from the terminal and then you can run the script by calling `./run.sh`.